# Light Tunnel into Basement (coming out of wall and coming from wooden deck)

Tags: lighting, basement

I have a basement conversion underway with three windows - one under a wooden deck.

This window opening is 27cm x 36cm (approx) and has a non opening double glazed unit with glass area of 20cm x 26cm.

I want to bring light into the basement via a light tunnel from the deck (about 90cm high) down into the basement.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Check out solartube.

Comment: I would also suggest solatube. However the amount of light may not be enough for you. How about a few photos

Comment: A shiny-on-the-inside duct with a clear cover to keep rain and dirt out of it. Purchased premade (preferably in a size larger than the window area if it's not the same shape - so a round one should be at least as big as the diagonals of the rectangular window) or DIY-ed as you see fit.  Or just go with two actual mirrors and build a periscope, which may have less light but more of a view. If you have an *ambitious* DIY mindset, have a microcontroller (or 19th century clockworks) drive a mirror to reflect sunlight into it (a heliostat.)